# Supporting Timezones in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got an application that allows users within the same company to create job records, view, edit, and search these jobs. The users are spread out all over the United States. A user in California may need to update a job for a user in New York and visa versa.

I read through an article that suggested setting `Time.zone` in the controller with a before action, but if I do this, I assume that Rails would then save that record in the current time zone for like the California user. Then, if the New York user updates the same record then `updated_at` time would then be in a different time zone than the `created_at` attribute. Ideally, I see all of my records having a UTC time and then when a given user accesses/creates records, the time is displayed to them in their set timezone but saved in the database as UTC. I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even the correct approach. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a little beyond S/O to help you with... but yes, that is the general idea of how to solve the problem. 1) accept time with timezone, 2) convert to UTC when storing, 3) convert to local when displaying.

Comment: For example, I would use relative time. I mean the server should use his reference time and each client its own. You then need to pick the current client time for doing calculation against the server time. So, times on server are consistent and clients just see a converted time. To get the client side time I guess you need some javascript to send this information to rails. Maybe [this gem](https://github.com/kbaum/browser-timezone-rails) can give some hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cannon Moyer if you see table structure of any table. updated_at and created_at columns store **timestamp without timezone**. When displaying, These values are automatically converted with timezone as application's timezone(UTC or IST) is set. so don't need to worry about time when a given user accesses/creates records.

For your case as @iGian suggested [this gem](https://github.com/kbaum/browser-timezone-rails) is useful for you. It sets the Rails timezone to the browser's configured timezone for each request.